# Bridge 2 LAN networks via SLIP on RS232

Tags: debian, iptables, bridge, route

I have a stupid problem (I hope) that is driving me crazy 
I've created a network, drawn below.

```
-------------+               ROUTER 1                 ROUTER 2
             |         +-----------------+     +------------------+ 
             |         |                 |     |                  |
   internet  |         | eth0            |     |             eth0 |       
             |         | 192.168.2.50/24 |     | 192.168.5.100/24 |-----+
  router     |----+----|                 |     |                  |     |
IP (LAN)     |    |    |                 |     |                  |     |
192.168.2.1  |    |    |                 |     |                  |     |
     (/24)   |    |    |             sl0 |     | sl0              |     |
             |    |    |    192.168.22.1 |-----| 192.168.22.2     |     |
-------------+    |    +-----------------+     +------------------+     |
                  |                                                     |
          +-----------------+                               +-----------------+
          | 192.168.2.2/24  |                               | 192.168.5.10/24 |
          | GW 192.168.2.254|                               | GW 192.168.5.100|
          |    CLIENT A     |                               |    CLIENT B     |
          +-----------------+                               +-----------------+
```

On both routers I have enabled IP_FORWARD and Debian as OS.

The goal is:

-Ensure that Client B can surf the Internet and access to 192.168.2.0/24 network.

-Client A must be able to reach the 192.168.5.0/24 network (and this is done by adding a simple route rule on client A) and obviously Internet.

The SLIP (sl0) connection is made via a 3-wire connection, with 2 USB-RS232 adapters (FT232 - FTDI chipset).
With the configurations below it is actually possible to do what I ask.
MTU of Sl0 it’s intentionally setting lower.

If from client B I try to open a web page, with TSHARK enabled on the sl0 interface, I see a high number of errors on TCP packets.

I see so many:

```
TCP Dup ACK
Time-to-live exceeded
TCP Retransmission
```

Which make it impossible to open a web page.

If instead I open the web page from router 2, the errors drop dramatically and it is possible (slowly) to navigate.

```
Start config of Sl0

## ROUTER 1
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 raw
modprobe slip
slattach -L -s 115200 -p cslip /dev/ttyUSB0 &
ifconfig sl0 192.168.22.1 dstaddr 192.168.22.2 mtu 296 txqueuelen 3
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen
route add -net 192.168.22.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.22.1
route add -net 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.22.2
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 296
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

## ROUTER 2
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 raw
modprobe slip
slattach -L -s 115200 -p cslip /dev/ttyUSB0 &
ifconfig sl0 192.168.22.2 dstaddr 192.168.22.1 mtu 296 txqueuelen 3
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen
route add -net 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.5.100
route add -net 192.168.22.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.22.2
ip route add default via 192.168.22.1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 296
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Where am I wrong?

I have some doubts about the configuration of IPTABLES and/or the routing map. 
I suspect that the packages bounce between the various interfaces

I’ve also tried this: [Change MSS in iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/892160/change-mss-in-iptables)
And there is a reduction a bit of error.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
####  Router 1 - routing table
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.5.0     192.168.22.2    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 sl0
192.168.22.0    192.168.22.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 sl0
192.168.22.2    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 sl0


####  Router 2 – routing table
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.22.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 sl0
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     200    0        0 eth0
192.168.22.0    192.168.22.2    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 sl0
192.168.22.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 sl0
```

Comment: You cannot bridge like that, but you can route between networks. Each router need to know about the network on the other side of the other router, and you really do not want to NAT between the networks.

Comment: You write "MTU of Sl0 it’s intentionally setting lower.". Can you elaborate why you have changed the MTU? Have you tried it without this MTU change?